# Method in Recyclerview is being called everytime i scroll

Tags: sqlite, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am using SQLite Database to store some value/items from recyclerview which are coming from Firebase by long press. And in that recyclerview i am changing background of the values/items which are already stored in SQLite database. But problem is that when I long press on any item, it also colors every 21st item in recyclerview. and then colors any random item when scrolling back to top.

**OnBindView**

```
holder.Card.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                    if (favDB.isFav(model.getUrl(), model.getName())) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Already in Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        new FavDB(getContext()).addToFav(
                                model.getName(), model.getType(), model.getUrl(),
                                model.getBrowser(), model.getImage());
                        holder.Card.setCardBackgroundColor(R.color.Background);
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Added to Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });

            if (favDB.isFav(model.getUrl(), model.getName())) {

                try {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Coloring", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.Card.setCardBackgroundColor(R.color.Background);
                    favDB.close();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error : " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

**SQLite Helper**

```
public void addToFav(String name, String type, String url, String browser, String image) {
    SQLiteDatabase favDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
    String favAdd =
            String.format("INSERT INTO fav(name,url) VALUES('%s','%s');",
                    name, type, url, browser, image);
    favDatabase.execSQL(favAdd);
    favDatabase.close();

}

public boolean isFav(String url, String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase favDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
    String masterQuery = String.format("SELECT * FROM fav WHERE (url= '%s' AND name = '%s')",
            url, name);

    Cursor cursor = favDatabase.rawQuery(masterQuery, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
    cursor.close();
    favDatabase.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is because you didn't hold the state of each item in your Adapter.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: You need to add a flag in your model data, for example: `private boolean isFavourite` which the value is set based on your database. Then check the state of favourite item in `onBindViewHolder` with it: `if(model.isFavourite()) { // set favourite view} else { // set not favourite.}`.

Comment: Btw, it's a good practice to move your database manipulation outside of the RecyclerView adapter by delegating the process to your Activity. Just think that adapter is only to show the items, no manipulation data at all.

Comment: But i am not calling data from sqlite. Data is coming from firebase, and only item marked as fav is store in sqlite. so i am check that with isFav() method.